# How to know in a middleware which type of url entered?

Tags: django, middleware, url-pattern

Recently I started a new simple project in Django. I wrote some middleware. but in one of the middlewares, I want to know which URL is called because I have to make a decision which is related to URL.

I used this code:

```
import os

path = os.environ['PATH_INFO']
```

but it makes an error which is described below:

```
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PATH_INFO'
```

so how I can know the URL in my middleware?

Comment: You can use `request.path_info`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the path in the `request` by using the [**`request.path`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path), or [**`request.path_info`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info). For example you can print the `path` with the following simple middleware:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class MyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        print(request.path)
```

You can make use of the [**`request.schema`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.schema) to access the schema of the URL (`http`, `https`, etc.), and the [**`request.method`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method) to access the method of the request (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, etc.).